# Problem leverage browse caching wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess

Hi we need to integrate the leveral browse caching in our site on ovh
gtmetrix exits this problem https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.curiosone.world/Oh2cgYli
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:

```
https://www.curiosone.de/favicon.ico (15 minutes)
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-699954844 (15 minutes)
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-699954844&l=dataLayer&cx=c (15 minutes)
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-143259546-1 (15 minutes)
https://amplify.outbrain.com/cp/obtp.js (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/734658696982369?v=2.9.18&r=stable (20 minutes)
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/plugins/identity.js?v=2.9.18 (20 minutes)
https://bat.bing.com/bat.js (30 minutes)
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (1 hour)
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js (1 hour)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
https://cdn.taboola.com/libtrc/unip/1218990/tfa.js (4 hours 1 second)
```

Is it possible to integrate it on our site for this data? If yes, how?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36998214/12787264). The answers should help you answer this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leverage browser caching for external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998214/leverage-browser-caching-for-external-files)

Answer (score 0):

Just on that site you mentioned there is a tutorial showing you how to enable caching in the `.htaccess` file on your server (you can access it using `FTP`):

https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html

Personally I use this piece of code for my website.

```
# Enable Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

This is one of the things that helped me to get a *Pagespeed Score* of 98% ...

Comment: You mean the french hoster? (https://www.ovh.com/fr/) If yes, probably. It does not matter where you host your website - as long as the servers interpret the `.htaccess` (which most servers do). Have you tried it yet?