# Optimisation of a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

My WordPress speed is too slow.I have install more than 20 plugins to customise the look and feel of my website. I can't understand is it the problem with too many plugins or any other issue. I have latest version of WordPress and formation pro theme which is already updated version 2.0.3.

How do I minimise the load time of my website on various browser. I have very poor Google page speed score.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all local resources are on your new domain otherwise you might run into [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580307/set-cache-control-to-external-resources).
All other resources that your site calls from exterior resources take a look here [set-cache-control-to-external-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580307/set-cache-control-to-external-resources)

Comment: Ok, Should I change the old subdomain to new one. So that all resources get a call from new domain.

Comment: you probably should